# Replace list element with element from another list based on condition

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, rule

I Have a list on integers and another list of "duplicates".
E.g.

`start={{3},{1},{2},{4}};
 duplicates={{1,4,7},{5,6}}`

I would like to substitute each element of **start** with the element (if it exists) of **duplicates** based on the following rule: if the first element at level 2 of an element at level 1 is equal to the element of start, then substitute it.

In this case the result list will be:

```
result={{3},{1,4,7,},{2},{4}}
```

Comment: To be clear, if `start` were `{{3},{1},{2},{4},{5},{8}}` then the `result` would be `{{3},{1,4,7,},{2},{4},{5,6},{8}}`?

Comment: @JasonB exactly. And there is no possibility to find `{8}` in `start`

Comment: @JasonB sorry, I mean  `{7}`

Comment: I think the method below should be fine even if there were a `{7}` in `start`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a set of replacement rules out of the `duplicates` list:

```
rules = ({#[[1]]} -> # & /@ duplicates)
(* {{1} -> {1, 4, 7}, {5} -> {5, 6}} *)
```

then apply it to any list like the ones you have,

```
{{3}, {1}, {2}, {4}} /. rules
(* {{3}, {1, 4, 7}, {2}, {4}} *)

{{3}, {1}, {2}, {4}, {5}, {8}} /. rules
(* {{3}, {1, 4, 7}, {2}, {4}, {5, 6}, {8}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `GroupBy`:

```
start1 /. GroupBy[duplicates, List@First@# &, Flatten]

(*{{3}, {1, 4, 7}, {2}, {4}}*)

start2 /. GroupBy[duplicates, List@First@# &, Flatten]

{{3}, {1, 4, 7}, {2}, {4}, {5, 6}, {8}}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `Lookup`:**

```
start1 = {{3}, {1}, {2}, {4}};
start2 = {{3}, {1}, {2}, {4}, {5}, {8}};
```

Generate a lookup table:

```
lut = First@# -> # & /@ duplicates
```

> {1 -> {1, 4, 7}, 5 -> {5, 6}}

```
Lookup[lut, First@#, #] & /@ start1
Lookup[lut, First@#, #] & /@ start2
```

> {{3}, {1, 4, 7}, {2}, {4}}

> {{3}, {1, 4, 7}, {2}, {4}, {5, 6}, {8}}

Answer (score 1):

```
start = {{3}, {1}, {2}, {4}};
duplicates = {{1, 4, 7}, {5, 6}};

ReplaceAll[MapApply[Sequence[{#} -> {##}] &] @ duplicates] @ start
```

{{3}, {1, 4, 7}, {2}, {4}}